# get an error in my django model related_name

Tags: django-models

this the problem

```
   raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
therapy.models.TherapyModule.invoice.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: TherapyModule has no invoice.
```

this my view

```
    for i in TherapyModule.objects.filter(query):
        index = 0
        if i:
            index += 1
            info_list = []
            info_list.append(i.invoice.title if i.invoice else "")
```

this my model

```
class InvoiceMoudle(models.Model):
    from examination.models import ExaminationModule
    from therapy.models import TherapyModule

    examination_info = models.OneToOneField(ExaminationModule, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True,related_name="invoice")
    therapy_info = models.OneToOneField(TherapyModule, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,related_name="invoice")
```

This code works fine in the development environment but throws the error mentioned above in the production environment. Please advise.